# gRPC greeter_client not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, protocol-buffers, grpc

After running greeter_client.rb, it is giving following exception

```
  ruby greeter_client.rb 
/Users/yashoda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails320/gems/grpc-1.4.1-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:46:in `check_status': 12: (GRPC::Unimplemented)
    from /Users/yashoda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails320/gems/grpc-1.4.1-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:178:in `attach_status_results_and_complete_call'
    from /Users/yashoda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails320/gems/grpc-1.4.1-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:340:in `request_response'
    from /Users/yashoda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails320/gems/grpc-1.4.1-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/client_stub.rb:167:in `request_response'
    from /Users/yashoda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails320/gems/grpc-1.4.1-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/service.rb:185:in `block (3 levels) in rpc_stub_class'
    from greeter_client.rb:46:in `main'
    from greeter_client.rb:50:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce what you're seeing here.

One guess is, it's possible that there is another grpc server running on your port "50051" (which greeter_server.rb starts up on).

By default, grpc servers bind ports with the SO_REUSEPORT option, so such a situation would be allowed. If wanted, you can disable SO_REUSEPORT by constructing the server with:

```
s = GRPC::RpcServer.new(server_args: { 'grpc.so_reuseport' => 0 })
```